# File provider extension not working on iOS 13

Tags: ios, file, ios13

I have an iOS app with a file provider extension.  The extension has three top-level virtual folders representing different groups of files our users have access to on the cloud.  The extension works great on iOS 12, but does not work correctly on iOS 13.

When loaded in the Files app, we are queried for the root container contents and enumerate the items correctly.  The three top-level folders show and are later updated with the number of items they contain asynchronously just fine.  The problem is that on iOS 13, when the user taps on one of the top-level folders to drill down to their contents, the Files app just pushes another copy of the root container on the stack.  This continues every time the user taps on one of our top-level folders.  They can never drill down into our folders.

As I said, the extension works fine on iOS 12.  Has anybody else seen this behavior?  I have verified that the NSFileProviderItems we are returning when enumerating contents have the type identifier set to kUTTypeFolder...and the capabilities of the items contains both .allowsContentEnumerating and .allowsReading.

Note that we are still building with Xcode 10.3.  We haven't been able to upgrade to Xcode 11 yet.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Even i am facing the same issue. For me it works until ios 13.0. After updating to 13.1 i am no longer able to select any files for download or viewing. In the documentation it shows "startProvidingItem" is deprecated from iOS 13.1. Not sure what is the alternative.